# Why is this docker build failing trying to install MySQL-python?

Tags: docker, pip, mysql-python

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
#RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install MySQL-python==1.2.5
```

When I build it I get the following error:

```
Step 4/4 : RUN pip install MySQL-python==1.2.5
 ---> Running in 60be606a8d3e
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting MySQL-python==1.2.5
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: MySQL-python
  Building wheel for MySQL-python (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for MySQL-python (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-IfSGpv/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-IfSGpv/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-oUG6qk --python-tag cp27
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-IfSGpv/MySQL-python/
  Complete output (38 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/include/mariadb -I/usr/include/mariadb/mysql -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o
  In file included from _mysql.c:44:
  /usr/include/mariadb/my_config.h:3:2: warning: #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h> [-Wcpp]
   #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h>
    ^~~~~~~
  In file included from _mysql.c:46:
  /usr/include/mariadb/mysql.h:440:3: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
     MYSQL_CLIENT_PLUGIN_HEADER
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_ping’:
  _mysql.c:2005:41: error: ‘MYSQL’ {aka ‘struct st_mysql’} has no member named ‘reconnect’
    if ( reconnect != -1 ) self->connection.reconnect = reconnect;
                                           ^
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for MySQL-python
  Running setup.py clean for MySQL-python
Failed to build MySQL-python
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python: started
    Running setup.py install for MySQL-python: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-IfSGpv/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-IfSGpv/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-Kpgfk8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-IfSGpv/MySQL-python/
    Complete output (38 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/include/mariadb -I/usr/include/mariadb/mysql -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o
    In file included from _mysql.c:44:
    /usr/include/mariadb/my_config.h:3:2: warning: #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h> [-Wcpp]
     #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h>
      ^~~~~~~
    In file included from _mysql.c:46:
    /usr/include/mariadb/mysql.h:440:3: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
       MYSQL_CLIENT_PLUGIN_HEADER
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_ping’:
    _mysql.c:2005:41: error: ‘MYSQL’ {aka ‘struct st_mysql’} has no member named ‘reconnect’
      if ( reconnect != -1 ) self->connection.reconnect = reconnect;
                                             ^
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-IfSGpv/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-IfSGpv/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-Kpgfk8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

If I uncomment the line `#RUN apt-get install python-pip python-dev libmysqlclient-dev`, I get the following error:

```
Step 3/5 : RUN apt-get install python-pip python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
 ---> Running in 5593492607c7
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package libmysqlclient-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev

E: Package 'libmysqlclient-dev' has no installation candidate
```

Then replacing `libmysqlclient-dev` with `libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev` just gets me back to my original error.

How can I install MySQL-python version 1.2.5 into my docker image??

Comment: what you are trying to do? Create your own image?

Answer (score 1):

According to DockerHub 
https://hub.docker.com/r/mikemanger/python27-mysql/
this is the way you can create your own image file

```
FROM python:2.7.13
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y mysql-server --no-install-recommends \
  && apt-get clean \
  && pip install PyMySQL \
  && pip install MySQL-python \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

might help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it relates to the fact that some MariaDB packages are being used but they aren't quite the same as MySQL native.

I still haven't found the solution for installing this package but I found a work around for my needs, I swapped out MySQL-python for mysql-connector-python in my requirements file.

or install directly in your Dockerfile;

```
RUN pip install mysql-connector-python
```

and then build my connections as per the MySQL Doc
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html